# Flask/Jinja content not centering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style all of my web page's content with CSS, but noticed that everything changes except for the scrambled words. Here is a screenshot showing my page:

[Boggle webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt77u.png)

What could be causing this issue? I've disabled caching, gave classes to the table row and table data elements that contain the letters as well covered the whole form in a wrapper and applied the css to those classes, but error persists. FIY I am using Jinjga templating. Here is my code:

CSS

```
.main-content,
.row{
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    color: red
}
```

FLASK/JINJA

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Board Form{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<div class='main-content'>
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for list in board %}
    <tr class="row">
    {% for char in list %}
        <td>{{char}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<form id="form" method="POST">
    <input id="guess" type="text" placeholder="Enter a guess" name="guess">
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<h3></h3>
<h1></h1>
<p>User has played {{ session["count"] }} times(s)</p>
<p>Highest Score: <b>{{ session["highest_score"] }}</b></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="/static/app.js"></script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

PYTHON

```
@app.route('/')
def create_board():
    """
    Root Route that creates game board 
    and stores it in session
    """
    board = boggle_game.make_board()
    session["board"] = board

    return render_template('board.html', board=board)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your main.css file following code:

```
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then change with the following line instead of table tag in board.html

```
<table class="center">
```